# Type mismatch when applying defined range to WorksheetFunction

Tags: vba, function, excel

Need to add in an if statement to control what I am looping through in my code so have started with this line:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Or(checkrange.value = 0, checkrange.value = "") = "False" Then
```

I have defined checkrange as the following

```
Set checkrange = finwb.Sheets("Strt_Dash_Final").Range(Cells((cfcll.Row + 1), q), Cells((cfcll.Row + (cfcll.value - 2)), q))
```

my code stops on the worksheet function line with run-time error 13, Type Mismatch. The purpose of the statment was to check if the range only contains 0s or blanks. The formula OR(A1:A5 = 0,A1:A5 = "") works fine in excel so I am assuming that it is not accepting my range in its current form (Note: i tried removing the .value from checkrange.value but this did not work either)

Any help on this, as always, is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT :** I have `Dim checkrange As range` to define it as a range

Comment: What is checkrange defined as/set to?

Comment: ah sorry, forgot to include that, I have Dim checkrange As range

Comment: You cannot compare a multiple cell range to one value using the `=` operator, as you are trying to do here. You should use `Worksheetfunction.Countif` instead. Also, your `Cells` references are not properly qualified with a worksheet in your range assignment. Sooner or later that will cause you a problem.

Comment: Range with more than one cells returns array. That's why it can't be compared to a value. If you can post the answer and accept it so that others know that the problem is solved.

Comment: **Not** `Countifs` but `Countif`. `Countifs` requires both criteria to be true.

Comment: @Rory could you post the solution for the `Countif`:  `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(checkrange, "= 0", checkrange, "= """) = 0 Then` I removed it from the question as it doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to be using a `WorksheetFunction` in the `If statement`.

```
If checkrange.value = 0 Or checkrange.value = "" Then
```

Because your checking a `Range` not a `Cell` you have to use `CountA` or `CountIf`

here is an example of `CountA`:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(checkrange) = 0 Then
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just tried it but still get type mismatch :?

Answer (score 1):

You need two separate COUNTIF statements:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(checkrange, "0") + Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(checkrange, "") = 0 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Or(checkrange.value = 0, checkrange.value = "") = False Then
```

though it's not really necessary to use worksheet function OR here. Have a try and let's see what happen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just tried it but still get type mismatch :?

Answer (score 0):

The array formula `OR(A1:A5 = 0,A1:A5 = "")` checks if **any** (1 or more) of the cells in the range are 0 or "". To check if any of the cells in the range are **not** 0 or "" then you can use this

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(checkrange, "<>0", checkrange, "<>") > 0 Then
```